# How to level checkbox with their tags in one line

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Here is a CheckBoxList.

The problem is that if the ListItem (text) has many words then the text displays in one line below its checkbox.

For some checkboxes, the characters appear smaller than usual.

Does anyone have any idea?

I would appreciate any advice.

Here's an example:[image]

Here's a sample of the code:

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  Example text
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chbList_1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Code">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CorpDicts %>" SelectCommand="select Code, Name from Base..Attributes"></asp:SqlDataSource>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add your code...

Comment: please add your html and css code

Comment: Solution 1: `put the checkbox and text inside seperate table columns`. Solution 2: `put them both inside seperate div elements within a container and float them next to eachother with css`. Solution 3: `Use Javascript to do it`. The point is: There are A LOT of ways to do what you want. Show us your code so we might actually give you a specific answer.

Comment: you can use `<table> ` for that purpose ,put check box on one column and put the topic on second column it will be correctly aligned .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving that you are using bootstrap the solution is built in already:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
</div>
```

[Complete example](https://jsfiddle.net/6f3nqp66/). Check out the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example)